# GIT: What happens to previous merges from master if I squash all commits on a branch and then merge it onto master?

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch I've been working on for a long time, regularly merging the main branch into it. So the history of this branch contains all of the commits from the main branch as well. I want to squash all of the commits into one commit on the branch, and then merge this branch back onto master. Will this affect the commit history on master?

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is that the history in a VCS is kept. So, there's no outcome if you simply add yet another commit.

But in git you *may* rewrite a history if you wish. If you have already published the original history, and some other persons have relied on it (that is, they have created their own commits on top of yours), then such a history rewrite would cause some pain for them - they will have to rebase their changes on top of the new history.

But if the history is still unpublished, or you can negotiate with your peers, and they're agree with the change, then you're free in your actions.

**Update**:
Since the altered branch has some merges from the master, I suppose that the initial picture of commits looks somewhat like this:

```
 A ---> B ---> C ---> D ---> E --> F (master)
  \             \            \
    --> BA --> BM1 -> BB --> BM2 --> BC (branch)
```

where `<letter>`s are `master` commits, `B<letter>`s are "own" `branch` commits, and `BM<number>`s are merges of `master` to `branch`.

Now you want to squash commits in the branch, so that the final picture would look like this:

```
 A ---> B ---> C ---> D ---> E --> F (master)
  \                          \
    -----------------------> BZ (branch)
```

*and* the file tree of `BZ` commit to be exactly the same as `BC` file tree.

The default behaviour of `git rebase` regarding merge commits is to flatten the history dropping merge records but replaying changes introduced by corresponding merges. Thus, if you simply issue `git checkout branch; git rebase -i A` and squash the commits to a single one, you will receive something like this:

```
 A ---> B ---> C ---> D ---> E --> F (master)
  \                          
    -----------------------> BZ (branch)
```

(notice the missing link between `E` and `BZ`)

So we need to perform some magic on rebasing. To simplify the task create tags `tagA` marking commit `A`, `tagE` marking commit `E`, and `tagBC` for `BC`. These tags could be safely deleted later when the job is done.

Now we're ready to proceed. Issue `git rebase -i tagA`. You'll be presented with a list like this:

```
pick 515de5f commit BA
pick 1c749c6 commit B
pick 4490402 commit C
pick 4da9e96 commit BB
pick 6d9dc01 commit D
pick 7e469d6 commit E
pick 861038b commit BC
```

Insert fake merge at the top of the list and replace all `pick`s with `fixup`s, so you'll get something like this:

```
exec git merge -s ours -m "The resulting commit" tagE
fixup 515de5f commit BA
fixup 1c749c6 commit B
fixup 4490402 commit C
fixup 4da9e96 commit BB
fixup 6d9dc01 commit D
fixup 7e469d6 commit E
fixup 861038b commit BC
```

Now save the file and quit. After the sequence is applied you'll get the desired commit structure. Test if `BZ` (head of the rewritten `branch`) is the same as the previous one (marked as `tagBC`), — it should be, — and you've done.

All standard practices for `git rebase` are applied: if something goes wrong you can always restart with `git rebase --abort`. If some conflicts occurred, you need to resolve them, and to continue with `git rebase --continue` and so on.

Comment: The idea is that I want master to see this merged in branch as a single commit. What I'm confused about is the fact that I branched off master at a particular point, and then kept merging master in along the way. So if I squash all of the commits, will master only make note of the differences in the merge? In other words, will master ignore all of the previous merges into the branch on the branch history, so there aren't two commit hashes for each change?

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely do that. You can do a squash off all commits on your branch.
Do a `git pull --rebase origin master` to make sure everything is in order. 
Resolve all conflicts and then merge to master.

Note :Typically when you are working on a branch say `branch_a` based of off say `master` it is recommended that you `rebase` off master rather than `merge` master in each time there is a change on master.

Comment: Do you have an example of rebasing off of master?

Comment: So if you are on branch "branch_a" perform the following command "git pull --rebase origin master" . Thats it.